# How can I schedule a build job on buildkite with block and fields parameter

Tags: buildkite

I have a build pipeline defined in buildkite as below:

```
- block: ":terraform: benchmark?"
    fields:
    - text: "name"
      key: "name"
      required: false
      default: "10"
```

It has a block which means it requires developers to unblock the step manually. Also it set a field used in the build step which means developers who unblock the step need to type in a value for the `name`. I wonder how I can schedule this job to let it run periodically? How can I make the scheduler unblocks the step and give a predefined value for `name` field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Customize your scheduled build message, add an if conditional for the block step to conditionally skip it, add another step to verify the value in metadata. I know this is complicated, but this is the simplest combination I can come up with.